# How to build a interactive decision tree in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First ever stack overflow question. Thanks in advance.

I’m trying to build a bootstrap site for users to arrive at an answer based on prior decisions.
Essentially, its an interactive decision tree.

**What I’m doing so far (I'm open to suggestions if there's an easier way of doing things)**

I’m using Bootstrap’s nav-pills for users to select their choice. The nav-pills opens other nav-pills and so on until the user reaches the end of the tree and arrive at an answer.
The issue i’m having is with the final “tabpanel” answers not hiding when the user goes back to the 1st decision and follows a different path.

I’ve included the code below.  To re-create the issue I’m having, please click on ‘1stYes’, then ‘2ndYesFrom1stYes’, then click ‘2ndNoFrom1stYes’.
As you can see, The previous answer is still appearing.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h2 class="text-center">User Decision Tree</h2>
      <br>
      <!-- First decision -->
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <h3 class="text-center">1st decision</h3>
        <br>
        <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#2ndDecisionYesFrom1st" aria-controls="2ndYes" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1stYes</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#2ndDecisionNoFrom1st" aria-controls="2ndNo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1stNo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <!-- Second decision -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <br>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2ndDecisionYesFrom1st">
          <h3 class="text-center">2nd Decision After Yes From First Decision</h3>
          <br>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#AnswerAfterYesFrom2ndYesFrom1st" role="tab">2ndYesFrom1stYes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#AnswerAfterNoFrom2ndYesFrom1st" role="tab">2ndNoFrom1stYes</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2ndDecisionNoFrom1st">
          <h3 class="text-center">2nd Decision After No From First Decision</h3>
          <br>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#AnswerAfterYesFrom2ndNoFrom1st" role="tab">2ndYesFrom1stNo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#AnswerAfterNoFrom2ndNoFrom1st" role="tab">2ndNoFrom1stNo</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <!-- Answers -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <br>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="AnswerAfterYesFrom2ndYesFrom1st">
          <h3 class="text-center">Answer after 2nd Decision Yes and 1st Decision Yes</h3>
          <br>
          <h4 class="text-center"><i>Here is the answer after 2nd Decision Yes and 1st Decision Yes</i></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <br>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="AnswerAfterNoFrom2ndYesFrom1st">
          <h3 class="text-center">Answer after 2nd Decision No and 1st Decision Yes</h3>
          <br>
          <h4 class="text-center"><i>Here is the answer after 2nd Decision No and 1st Decision Yes</i></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <br>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="AnswerAfterYesFrom2ndNoFrom1st">
          <h3 class="text-center">Answer after 2nd Decision Yes and 1st Decision No</h3>
          <br>
          <h4 class="text-center"><i>Here is the answer after 2nd Decision Yes and 1st Decision Yes</i></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <br>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="AnswerAfterNoFrom2ndNoFrom1st">
          <h3 class="text-center">Answer after 2nd Decision No and 1st Decision No</h3>
          <br>
          <h4 class="text-center"><i>Here is the answer after 2nd Decision No and 1st Decision Yes</i></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an attribute called 'level' to the different levels.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" level="1">
```

And then add some js to close the tabs with higher levels. (An opened tab gets class 'active'. Removing it will close it.)

```
$('a[role=tab]').on('click', function (e) {
    var clickLevel = Number($(e.target).parent('li').attr('level'));
    $('div.tab-pane.active').each(function () {
        if (Number($(this).attr('level')) > clickLevel) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
});
```

Edit: I made the selector $('a[role=tab]') more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply burktelefon. 
I’m a little unsure about how to use your solution. Can I trouble you to implement it to my code as an example?

Comment: At the moment I'm a bit too busy, but I'll try to get some time for it later.